# How do I make Intellij stop removing Grails inline plugin module dependencies?

Tags: ide, grails, dependencies, intellij-idea, grails-plugin

I am developing a Grails application along with a Grails plugin used by that application. In Intellij, I have defined two modules: one for the application, and one for the plugin. In my application's BuildConfig.groovy, I have defined the plugin dependency as a maven dependency, because when it is built/deployed to the production server, it should only refer to the latest 'released' version of the plugin. I override this dependency in my ~/.grails/settings.groovy file with my inline plugin location, so that I don't have to worry about accidentally committing my local development settings to the repository.

This works great when I use the built in grails commands to build/run/test, etc, but it has one fatal flaw: every time I do a clean, and periodically even when I don't, Intellij will read the application's BuildConfig.groovy file and *remove* the plugin module as a dependency for the grails app! This is extremely frustrating, as I have to then manually go to File -> Project Structure, select the application module, select the dependencies tab, and manually add the plugin's module dependency to it.  Every. Single. Time.

Is there some way I can make Intellij leave my grails app's module dependencies alone, and trust that I know what I'm doing when I assign them? This is getting ridiculous!

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid that's a bug in IDEA. I've created a bug request for this issue: http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEA-56472. There you can find the way to temporarily fix this issue.

Comment: Thanks for filing a bug report! I tried to apply the plugin fix that was attached, but doing so causes Idea to fail whenever I start it with the following message:

Fatal error initializing class com.intellij.util.indexing.FileBasedIndex: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError